# docker-compose postgres container connects to django container locally but not on github actions

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

I have a project with three containers: python, nodejs, and postgres. The python container is for django and the nodejs container is for react. I'm using docker compose to run all of these containers together. Locally, everything runs properly.

When running docker-compose in github actions django can't connect to the postgres container.

The error on github actions is:

```
django    | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
django    |     Is the server running on host "***" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
django    |     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
django    | could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
django    |     Is the server running on host "***" (::1) and accepting
django    |     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

But the postgres container says it is starting fine and accepting connections:

```
db_1      | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
db_1      | 
db_1      | 2023-03-16 18:35:55.273 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.2 (Debian 15.2-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
db_1      | 2023-03-16 18:35:55.274 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1      | 2023-03-16 18:35:55.274 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1      | 2023-03-16 18:35:55.277 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1      | 2023-03-16 18:35:55.282 UTC [63] LOG:  *** system was shut down at 2023-03-16 18:35:55 UTC
db_1      | 2023-03-16 18:35:55.289 UTC [1] LOG:  *** system is ready to accept connections
```

Here is the compose file:

```
services:
  django:
    hostname: django
    container_name: django
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: dev.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/backend
    environment:
      - SECRET_KEY=development_secret
      - DEBUG=1
      - DB_HOST=${DB_HOST}
      - DB_NAME=${DB_NAME}
      - DB_USER=${DB_USER}
      - DB_PASS=${DB_PASS}
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - backend
    command: sh -c "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"

  nodejs:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: dev.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - backend
    command: sh -c "npm install && npm run start"

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports: 
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - backend
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -d $${POSTGRES_DB} -U $${POSTGRES_USER}" ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

networks:
  backend:
    name: network
    driver: bridge
```

This is the github actions yml file:

```
name: Django CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev/**
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - dev/**

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      SECRET_KEY: development_secret
      DEBUG: 1
      DB_HOST: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
      DB_NAME: ${{ secrets.NAME }}
      DB_USER: ${{ secrets.USER }}
      DB_PASS: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}

      POSTGRES_DB: ${{ secrets.NAME }}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${{ secrets.USER }}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up containers
        run: docker-compose up
      - name: Run Django tests
        run: docker exec django python manage.py test
```

I'm running docker-compose without the -d flag so I can see the output of the containers on github actions.

Comment: You should include postgres as a service in your github action. You can also use this image (https://github.com/singularit-de/django-test) to run the test on or have a look at the ci workflow.